# Finding the Rank of power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be $6 \times 6$ matrix with $A^5 = I$, Find the rank($A^2$).

The only thing I can think about this question is
$A^5 = I$ implies $x^5 - 1 =0$ is annihilating polynomial. Can I conclude or continue solving the problem with that idea ?

How can we solve these type of problems. What are the results I have to know. Is there a general idea for solving them ??

Comment: $\ker(A^2)\subseteq\ker(A^5)=\{0\}$

Comment: What Kernel you are talking about ? Kernel of which mapping ?

Comment: Kernels of the linear transformations whose matrices are $A^2$ and $A^5$. It is common to refer them as kernels of their matrices...

Comment: $6=\text{rank}\big(I_6\big)=\text{rank}\big(A^5\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A^4\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A^3\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A^2\big)\leq \text{rank}\big(A\big)\leq 6$

Comment: Is that a result ? rank($A^k$) $\leq$ rank($A^{k+1}$)

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$A^2A^3=A^3A^2=A^5=I.$$

Thus, $A^2$ is inverible. Conclusion ?

Comment: Does it implies that the $\text{rank}{A^k}=n$ for every idempotent A?

Comment: @LevonMinasian Idempotent matrix means $A^2=A$. So $A^k=A$ and $\text{rank} A^k=\text{rank}A$. For example the zero matrix is idempotent and not full rank.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri my bad. Consider the matrix $A$ s.t. $A^m=1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I thought using the proof above we can show that $\text{rank} A^k=n$ for every k.

Comment: @LevonMinasian Yes you can. $A^m=I\implies A$ is (invertible) bijective so $A^k$ is a composition of bijections hence bijective. Alternatively simply observe that $|A^k|=|A|^k\ne0~~\because |A|\ne0$.

Comment: $A^2$ is invertible implies it has non zero determinant and hence rank has to be 6 !?

Comment: @Karthik That is correct. However, you don't need determinants to argue that an invertible matrix has full rank!